# Failed to attach storage on server

Tags: dell, xenserver, dell-perc

## **Server Datasheet:**

```
Dell R710
RAM : 32 GB
Local storage 0 : Sata SSD 1 TB 
Local storage 1 : SAS Dell-perc Raid 1 (1 TB total)
XEN Server 7.1
```

## What is happened?

After shutdown the Xen hypervisor is displaying a message:
Failed to attach storage on server.

I tried to repair my local storage, however no success!

[image]

## After try to repair

```
[root@XEN01 ~]# xe sr-list type=lvm
uuid ( RO)                : 2d4ea1f5-9c32-5adb-96fb-d83383893966
          name-label ( RW): Local_storage_0
    name-description ( RW):
                host ( RO): XEN01
                type ( RO): lvm
        content-type ( RO): user


uuid ( RO)                : a30e9302-4a58-da91-5370-b0a492f4e303
          name-label ( RW): Local_storage_1
    name-description ( RW):
                host ( RO): XEN01
                type ( RO): lvm
        content-type ( RO): user


[root@XEN01 ~]# xe pbd-list sr-uuid=a30e9302-4a58-da91-5370-b0a492f4e303
uuid ( RO)                  : 6b82b3da-6253-a12a-880f-39d7019d1fce
             host-uuid ( RO): b0b1cfbf-ddf0-4ebb-ad1b-2fe52f6ebe74
               sr-uuid ( RO): a30e9302-4a58-da91-5370-b0a492f4e303
         device-config (MRO): device: /dev/sdb
    currently-attached ( RO): false


[root@XEN01 ~]# xe pbd-plug uuid=6b82b3da-6253-a12a-880f-39d7019d1fce
Error code: SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_47
Error parameters: , The SR is not available [opterr=no such volume group: VG_XenStorage-a30e9302-4a58-da91-5370-b0a492f4e303],
[root@XEN01 ~]#
```

## All params (Local_storage_1)

```
[root@XEN01 ~]# xe sr-list name-label=Local_storage_1 params=all
uuid ( RO)                    : a30e9302-4a58-da91-5370-b0a492f4e303
              name-label ( RW): Local_storage_1
        name-description ( RW):
                    host ( RO): XEN01
      allowed-operations (SRO): unplug; plug; PBD.create; update; PBD.destroy; VDI.resize; forget; VDI.clone; scan; VDI.snapshot; VDI.mirror; VDI.create; VDI.destroy
      current-operations (SRO):
                    VDIs (SRO): 9beef78b-f648-49d3-bb60-a643ac62d619; e9315a06-9dc6-45d0-b97c-ae52a9015157; 77863808-8028-47d2-986d-018449575801; d79c6edc-9aeb-4c11-ac2d-a273a05c0aeb; 085dcc00-4b59-4021-aeda-2cbbb25dc645; c8a30c68-615f-4d5b-a922-2c517fd7dbbb; 34e8f591-96a5-49cb-983d-b9a30986762b; d0a1b00d-3eb6-4402-a588-d571104f361a; 2464fb97-0d6a-432b-acd3-5d05b876ee88; be8cfbad-e291-4e40-b8bf-65a17f26f2cc
                    PBDs (SRO): 6b82b3da-6253-a12a-880f-39d7019d1fce
      virtual-allocation ( RO): 773094113280
    physical-utilisation ( RO): 556621889536
           physical-size ( RO): 1999831564288
                    type ( RO): lvm
            content-type ( RO): user
                  shared ( RW): false
           introduced-by ( RO): <not in database>
             is-tools-sr ( RO): false
            other-config (MRW): dirty: ; trim_last_triggered: 1498060488.05
               sm-config (MRO): allocation: thick; use_vhd: true; devserial: scsi-36a4badb051ef180020634acf1fe721b4
                   blobs ( RO):
     local-cache-enabled ( RO): false
                    tags (SRW):
               clustered ( RO): false
```

## Checksum error

```
[root@XEN01 ~]# vgdisplay
  /dev/sdb: Checksum error
  Couldn't read volume group metadata.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VG_XenStorage-2d4ea1f5-9c32-5adb-96fb-d83383893966
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  651
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                16
  Open LV               6
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               935.98 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              239612
  Alloc PE / Size       152631 / 596.21 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       86981 / 339.77 GiB
  VG UUID               ReeFFw-NKGi-J7if-Kuuy-fkSd-8qQU-9YiQLq


[root@XEN01 ~]# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  /dev/sdb: Checksum error
  Couldn't read volume group metadata.
  Found volume group "VG_XenStorage-2d4ea1f5-9c32-5adb-96fb-d83383893966" using metadata type lvm2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to go deeper and try fixing at the LVM level by yourself. XenServer will not attempt to do that sort of repair by itself.

The key, IMHO is the `/dev/sdb: Checksum error` output which usually has to do corruption of the LVM metadata. As you can see, only one logical volume is seen, and the one defined on that storage pool, `VG_XenStorage-a30e9302-4a58-da91-5370-b0a492f4e303` is not found.

Take a look at [this article](https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/appnote/19386.html), under "Corrupted LVM Meta Data" for ideas and options.

Of course, I **would definitively** create an image of `/dev/sdb` before doing anything on it.